# Is it possible to use previous field values in labels or titles in Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there any way to pipe values from fields into the labels or titles of future fields or sections?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

At the moment we do not have a way to display field values as field labels, or pull values into field labels. This is a feature that is on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/j4RleM44).